# In Laravel blade file @include, everything is included except the <style> tags inside the file! They're being thrown away somewhere

Tags: laravel

I have a weird thing going on. In a Laravel blade file, everything is included except the  tags inside the file! They're being thrown away somewhere.

Please assist if you know what may be going on. Thanks so much.

Comment: could you give us more info or code? I dont really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in laravel goto layouts->yourLayout_name.blade.php and in this layout add styles, css just like this > @stacks('styles')

if your include blade just add @push('styles') @endpush

Comment: if not work then send me the pic of directory include and layouts blade

Comment: It's `@stack` not `@stacks`